# Can't extend my custom gutenberg block

Tags: block-editor

I have been trying to extend some custom blocks I coded along with core blocks to support custom CSS.

This is how tried to extend the block attributes

```
const {assign} = lodash;

const {__} = wp.i18n;

const {hasBlockSupport} = wp.blocks;

const {PanelBody} = wp.components;

const {createHigherOrderComponent} = wp.compose;

const {InspectorControls} = wp.blockEditor || wp.editor;

const {Fragment} = wp.element;

const {addFilter} = wp.hooks;

/**
 * Internal dependencies.
 */
import './style.scss';

import CSSEditor from './editor.js';

import './inject-css.js';

const addAttribute = (settings) => {
    console.log(settings);
    if (hasBlockSupport(settings, 'customClassName', true)) {
        settings.attributes = assign(settings.attributes, {
            hasCustomCSS: {
                type: 'boolean',
                default: false
            },
            customCSS: {
                type: 'string',
                default: null
            }
        });
    }

    return settings;
};

const withInspectorControls = createHigherOrderComponent((BlockEdit) => {
    return (props) => {
        const hasCustomClassName = hasBlockSupport(props.name, 'customClassName', true);
        if (hasCustomClassName && props.isSelected) {
            return (
                <Fragment>
                    <BlockEdit {...props} />
                    <InspectorControls>
                        <PanelBody
                            title={__('Additional CSS')}
                            initialOpen={false}>
                            <CSSEditor
                                clientId={props.clientId}
                                setAttributes={props.setAttributes}
                                attributes={props.attributes}
                            />
                        </PanelBody>
                    </InspectorControls>
                </Fragment>
            );
        }

        return <BlockEdit {...props} />;
    };
}, 'withInspectorControl');

addFilter('blocks.registerBlockType', 'attire-blocks/custom-css', addAttribute);
addFilter('editor.BlockEdit', 'attire-blocks/with-inspector-controls', withInspectorControls);
```

The thing is, custom attributes I introduced (`hasCustomCSS` and `customCSS`) are applied to core blocks are not applied to blocks I made! Also, see the `console.log(settings);`. This only prints core blocks, mine are not shown.

**EDIT:**
This is how I am applying the attributes:

```
add_action('wp_head', array($this, 'apply_custom_css'));



  public function apply_custom_css()
    {
        if (function_exists('has_blocks') && has_blocks(get_the_ID())) {
            global $post;

            if (!is_object($post)) {
                return;
            }

            $blocks = $this->parse_blocks($post->post_content);

            if (!is_array($blocks) || empty($blocks)) {
                return;
            }

            $style = "\n" . '<style type="text/css" media="all" id="atbs-ccss">' . "\n";
            $style .= $this->get_block_custom_css($blocks);
            $style .= "\n" . '</style>' . "\n";

            echo $style;
        }
    }





  public function get_block_custom_css($inner_blocks)
    {
        $style = '';
        foreach ($inner_blocks as $block) {
            if (isset($block['attrs'])) {
                if (isset($block['attrs']['hasCustomCSS']) && isset($block['attrs']['customCSS'])) {
                    $style .= $block['attrs']['customCSS'];
                }
            }

            if ('core/block' === $block['blockName'] && !empty($block['attrs']['ref'])) {
                $reusable_block = get_post($block['attrs']['ref']);

                if (!$reusable_block || 'wp_block' !== $reusable_block->post_type) {
                    return;
                }

                if ('publish' !== $reusable_block->post_status || !empty($reusable_block->post_password)) {
                    return;
                }

                $blocks = $this->parse_blocks($reusable_block->post_content);

                $style .= $this->get_block_custom_css($blocks);
            }

            if (isset($block['innerBlocks']) && !empty($block['innerBlocks']) && is_array($block['innerBlocks'])) {
                $style .= $this->get_block_custom_css($block['innerBlocks']);
            }
        }
        return $style;
    }
```

**Edit 2** : the CSSEditor component

```
const CSSEditor = ({attributes, setAttributes, clientId}) => {
useEffect(() => {
    if (attributes.customCSS) {
        customCSSRef.current = (attributes.customCSS).replace(/.atbs-ccss-[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*/g, 'wrapper');
    } else {
        customCSSRef.current = 'wrapper {\n}\n';
    }

    editorRef.current = wp.CodeMirror(document.getElementById('atbs-css-editor'), {
        value: customCSSRef.current,
        autoCloseBrackets: true,
        continueComments: true,
        lineNumbers: true,
        lineWrapping: true,
        matchBrackets: true,
        lint: true,
        gutters: ['CodeMirror-lint-markers'],
        styleActiveLine: true,
        styleActiveSelected: true,
        extraKeys: {
            'Ctrl-Space': 'autocomplete',
            'Alt-F': 'findPersistent',
            'Cmd-F': 'findPersistent'
        }
    });

    editorRef.current.on('change', () => {
        const regex = new RegExp('wrapper', 'g');
        customCSSRef.current = editorRef.current.getValue().replace(regex, `.${classArRef.current}`);

        if (('wrapper {\n}\n').replace(/\s+/g, '') === customCSSRef.current.replace(/\s+/g, '')) {
            return setAttributes({customCSS: null});
        }
        setAttributes({customCSS: customCSSRef.current});
    });
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    let classes = getClassName();

    setAttributes({
        hasCustomCSS: true,
        className: classes
    });
}, [attributes]);

const getClassName = () => {
    let classes;

    const uniqueId = clientId.substr(0, 8);

    if (null !== customCSSRef.current && ('wrapper {\n}\n').replace(/\s+/g, '') === customCSSRef.current.replace(/\s+/g, '')) {
        return attributes.className;
    }

    if (attributes.className) {
        classes = attributes.className;

        if (!classes.includes('atbs-ccss-')) {
            classes = classes.split(' ');
            classes.push(`atbs-ccss-${uniqueId}`);
            classes = classes.join(' ');
        }

        classArRef.current = classes.split(' ');
        classArRef.current = classArRef.current.find(i => i.includes('atbs-ccss'));
    } else {
        classes = `atbs-ccss-${uniqueId}`;
        classArRef.current = classes;
    }

    return classes;
};

const editorRef = useRef(null);
const customCSSRef = useRef(null);
const classArRef = useRef(null);

return (
    <Fragment>
        <p>{__('Add your custom CSS.')}</p>

        <div id="atbs-css-editor" className="atbs-css-editor"/>

        <p>{__('Use')} <code>wrapper</code> {__('to target block wrapper.')}</p>
        <p>{__('')}</p>
        <p>{__('Example:')}</p>

        <pre className="atbs-css-editor-help">
            {'wrapper {\n    background: #000;\n}\n\nwrapper img {\n    border-radius: 100%;\n}'}
        </pre>

        <p>{__('You can also use other CSS syntax here, such as media queries.')}</p>
    </Fragment>
);
```

};

Comment: If the blocks you made are under your control, could you not add the CSS support directly to them without needing the filter? It would make sense that your own blocks would not make use of this new attribute if you never made them use it

Comment: @TomJNowell the thing is I want to apply these attributes to all blocks. Also, apply them all at once to all of my blocks instead of manually adding one by one.

Comment: And you've succesfully added the attribute, but that doesn't mean it's going to be used. Adding the information to the blocks attributes and providing a UI to edit it doesn't mean you've added output to the block. Just as adding a metabox that updates a `foobar` post meta value doesn't mean all posts will know to render that post metas value, you have to do something with the attributes or it's just a data store with a fancy editing UI. Your blocks don't display that attribute because there is no code to do that. The core blocks do

Comment: @TomJNowell I am applying those attributes to `wp_head`(inside a style tag). For core blocks, those styles are applied. For my blocks, no. What is happening is those attributes are not being saved when I save the page/post. I just can't figure why that happens for my blocks but not the core blocks.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the attributes are not being saved? How did you check? Just because you don't see the styles being applied doesn't mean the attribute was not saved. Why would the styles be applied? There is no code to apply them. Have you check the comment tags and inspected the raw attributes to check that is the case? If the goal is to avoid duplicating work, wouldn't you just build it once in a component then add that component to all your blocks?

Comment: I logged attributes in the respective blocks I made changes to, there is no `hasCustomCSS` or `customCSS` attributes when I refresh after writing some CSS in the input field. Check the edit section of my question, I assign a custom class to the block them add the CSS to that class and append in the head section. The className is applied to the block but the CSS section is empty.

Comment: hmmm I see, you could eliminate `hasCustomCSS` by just checking if `customCSS` is empty or not. Can you include the implementation of the `CSSEditor` component?

Comment: Updated the description.

Comment: Did you add the right file? There are no components in the extra code you posted and no mention of `CSSEditor`

Comment: Sorry, Updated.